# Как реализовать визуализацию звуковой дорожки(примерно как голосовое в вк) в RN?

Tags: react-native

Нужно реализовать вот такой компонент
[image: макет]

Нормальных примеров найти не смог, да и с react native только знакомлюсь, мб кто-то делал и может показать свой пример или знаете где можно найти на просторах интернета, буду очень признателен